# Пересечение прямой и коллайдера Unity

Tags: unity3d

Пишу игру, в которой нужно управлять отрядом солдат.  Есть матрица проходимости и коллайдеры, там где пройти нельзя (для различных эффектов, кода некоторых солдат будет раскидывать во все стороны, чтоб в стены не залетали). Поиск пути для отряда занимает достаточно много времени, и отсюда такой вопрос: можно ли в Unity проверить пересекает ли определенный отрезок какой либо коллайдер?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А) прямая пересекает коллайдер и отряд ищет путь по алгоритму поиска пути. Б) прямая не пересекает коллайдер и отряд идет на прямую.

Ну или может посоветуете что по лучше?)

Update: извиняюсь, забыл написать, что игра 2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для проверки пересечения вы можете использовать [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html). То есть вы задаете луч из точки откуда идет ваш отряд в точку, куда он должен прийти и в зависимости от заданных в Raycast параметров (маски коллизий например) Unity выдаст вам ответ - пересекает луч что-либо, или нет, и если пересекает, то также даст информацию об объекте и точке пересечения. Использование Raycast является нес

Теоретически есть вторая возможность - самому вычислять вектор движения (математический вектор, не путать с классами семейства Vector в Unity) и с помощью математических формул искать пересечения с каким-либо объектом. Но В вашем случае данное решение точно не подойдет, потому что даже судя по рисунку у вас могут быть объекты с большим количеством вершин, и решить задачу такого пересечения будет крайне сложно. Такой подход может помочь только с простыми примитивами, типа прямоугольников.

Answer (score 3):

Такой компонент как **NavmeshAgent** по сути за вас это делает, ищет путь и кидает *райкасты* свои. Дополнительно на объекты надо вешать **obstacle**.

В ответ на ваш вопрос:
Можно конкретно взять **Collider** и вызвать на нем функцию **Raycast**( проверка луча только с этим коллайдером, в отличии от **Physics.Raycast**, функция намного дешевле)